# Google Chrome JSON.encode / decode array

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

So, I'm writing a little Greasemonkey Userscript and its working fine in Firefox however if I try to run it with Tampermonkey on Googles Chrome I get weird erros when encoding/decoding arrays.

I try to make the Script cross browser compatible so I had to write a function to decide which JSON methods to use

```
function jsonEncode(string) { 
  try {
    return JSON.stringify(string); 
  } catch (e) {
    return JSON.encode(string); 
  }
}

function jsonDecode(obj) {
  try { 
    return JSON.parse(obj); 
  } catch (e) { 
    return JSON.decode(obj);
  }
}
```

To simplify things I have now reduced the code to a simple array and the attempt to encode/decode and iterate

```
var array = ['string1', 'string2'];

var encoded = jsonEncode(array);
localStorage.setItem('json_test', encoded);

var decoded = jsonDecode(localStorage.getItem('json_test'));
for(var i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
    console.log(decoded[i]); 
}
```

I expect the output to be

```
string1
string2
```

instead chrome gives me this

```
[
"
s
t
r
i
n
g
1
"
,
"
s
t
r
i
n
g
2
"
]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this, or why chrome is doing that?

**EDIT 1:** Chrome Version 15.0.874.121 m

**EDIT 2:** have still not figured it out but when I try it with an object instead of an array it works so I will do  it this way now, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/TRxBM/) Can you try reproducing it on http://jsfiddle.net? Also, what version of Chrome and what OS?

Comment: Chrome Version is 15.0.874.121 m Will try to reproduce it with Fiddle..

Comment: Ok, so it seems to work if I post the code on jsfiddle.net ... that raises the question why it would not work within tampermonkey ...

Comment: @grrrrr I wanna I ask just to learn it. Does `JSON.stringify` is not browser compatible and why to need to use `JSON.encode`?

Comment: At first I just used JSON.stringify which works fine in Firefox as soon as I tried it in Chrome/Opera I got errors and apparently these two don't know stringify so I searched for the stringify alternative which is encode, and with the try and catch it now works cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open JS console in Chrome - this let's you set breakpoints in the loop - and add watches on variables.

Beside that jsonDecode doesn't decode - there's still the brackets...

The problem is that you decode to string as is seems - that why it slices the string in letters - just as you coded it.

JSON ordinary represents arrays ... maybe check the documentation for correct output parameters.

Comment: ... or probably localStorage.setItem() doesn't support arrays?

why not just try an array in RAM instead?

Comment: as far as I know localStorage only supports strings, that why Im running everything I want to save to localStorage through JSON

Comment: JSON basically is a string - which is representing a JS object in plain-text - hence the name.